# What's the easiest way to find a kindOf class in an array, and replace it in Swift?

Tags: swift, loops, replace

I'm moving from Obj-C to Swift and am in that stage of finding the simplest things to be difficult.

I have an array `models`

I need to loops through `models` and look for a isKindOfClass `modelFoo`.

Once the `modelFoo` type is found, I want to replace what's there with `newModel`.

Comment: Share related code. Even if it's objective-c. Show us what you have done and what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Probably this code will help you (from playground):

```
class ModelFoo {}
class NewModel {}

let models: [Any] = [ModelFoo(), NewModel()]

let result = models.map { $0 as? NewModel ?? NewModel() }
```

You just check type of the every element in `models` array and try casting this element to `NewModel` type. If you can not cast this element to `NewModel` type, you will get nil which later will be replaced by new `NewModel` instance. So, as a result you will get an array with elements of `NewModel` type.

**OR**

Use this code as result array:

```
let result: [Any] = models.map {
    guard $0 is ModelFoo else { return $0 }
    return NewModel()
}
```

The difference is the second implementation supports case when `models` array consist of not only of `ModelFoo` and `NewModel` instance and you want to replace **only** ModelFoo instances and leave other ones.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you, I've just added one more implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Generic Solution:

```
struct Foo {
    var name: String
}

struct Bar {
    var name: String
}

struct Baz {
    var name: String
}

//Your array of different models
var models: [Any] = [Foo(name: "Some 1"),
                     Bar(name: "Other 1"),
                     Foo(name: "Some 2"),
                     Bar(name: "Other 2"),
                     Foo(name: "Some 3"),
                     Bar(name: "Other 3")]

//Loop through the array
models = models.map { (model) -> Any in
    if let fooModel = model as? Foo {
        /*
         Testing if model typecasts to Foo.
         If it does then the current iteration is on the Foo model
         */

        //Translate Foo to Baz
        let newModel = Baz(name: "Replaced: \(fooModel.name)")

        return newModel
    }

    //If the above typecast fails, return whatever the current item is
    return model
}

print(models)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your array "in place" you could use a variation of Vlad's (excellent) answer:

```
class ModelFoo {}
class NewModel {}

var models: [Any] = [ModelFoo(), NewModel(),ModelFoo(), NewModel()]

models.enumerated().forEach {
    if $0.1 is ModelFoo {
        models[$0.0] = NewModel()
    }
}
```